# ajax data with datatables js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so.. i have an ajax read from database using an api controller (GET method)
the data that is coming back from the ajax is correct but i cant seem to populate it into datatables

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: webRoot + "/api/report",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "GET",
                //data: JSON.stringify(),
                success: function (tData) {
                    loadData(tData);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                },
            });
        
        });

        function loadData(tData) {
            $("#example").DataTable({
                data: tData
            });
        }
```

this is my latest try:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#example").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/report",
                    type: "GET"
                }
            });
        });
```

and this is the error i get in console:

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear if there is a specific reason you are doing so much out side of DataTables. See AJAX Example: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html Also you example does not show where `webroot` is defined.

Comment: You might find this as a better reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: @Twisty has a good point. It would be better to use DataTables with the internal ajax function so you can leverage all the associated functionality to update the table as well. Or explain in greater detail why you need the ajax external to the DataTables framework so we can better understand what you are going for.

Comment: i now tryed it like so:
edited the question itself

Comment: @PavelBratslavsky "Connection Refused" sounds like the Web Server is not running or accepting connections. That would not be an AJAX issue, but a server issue. Try using `./api/report` assuming the page loading it is already at `https://localhost/`

Comment: so.. there is no connection refued no more but im getting a different error, edited the question with the error

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```
$(function() {
  var webroot = ".";
  $("#example").DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: webroot + "/api/report"
    }
  });
});
```

You will want to test your `url` manually in browser to ensure that you're getting expected results.

**Update**

Consider the following code based on what you're using.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  ajax: {
    url: webRoot + "/api/report",
    dataSrc: function (res) {
      var json = {
        data: []
      };
      $.each(res, function(k, v){
        json.data.push([
          v.EmployeeId,
          v.FirstName,
          v.LastName,
          v.Title,
          v.TotalCustomers,
          v.TotalSales
        ]);
      });
      return json;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: this is the error im getting now:

jquery.dataTables.js:4788 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

at jquery.dataTables.js:4788
at callback (jquery.dataTables.js:3900)
at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.js:3930)
at fire (jquery-3.4.1.js:3291)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.js:3421)
at done (jquery-3.4.1.js:9533)"
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.js:9785)

Comment: @PavelBratslavsky this would suggest that there is no return payload. Would advise checking Console and Network for more detail on the request. Maybe JSON is not being return? What do you see when you navigate directly to the API?

Comment: Thank you i got it... just has to make an array and push the ajax data into it than pass it to the data table.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone issue solved just needed to push the data from the ajax pull to an array of objects than to the data table.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: webRoot + "/api/report",
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "GET",
                //data: JSON.stringify(),
                //processing: true,
                success: function (res) {
                    //loadData(res);
                    var return_data = new Array();
                    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                        return_data.push({
                            0: res[i].EmployeeId,
                            1: res[i].FirstName,
                            2: res[i].LastName,
                            3: res[i].Title,
                            4: res[i].TotalCustomers,
                            5: res[i].TotalSales,
                        });
                    }

                    $("#example").DataTable({
                        data: return_data,
                    });
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                },
            });
        });
```